# Iterate through excel files' sheets and append if sheet names share common part in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openxlsx

Let's say we have many excel files with the multiple sheets as follows:

Sheet 1: `2021_q1_bj`

```
   a  b   c  d
0  1  2  23  2
1  2  3  45  5
```

Sheet 2: `2021_q2_bj`

```
   a  b   c  d
0  1  2  23  6
1  2  3  45  7
```

Sheet 3: `2019_q1_sh`

```
   a  b   c
0  1  2  23
1  2  3  45
```

Sheet 4: `2019_q2_sh`

```
   a  b   c
0  1  2  23
1  2  3  40
```

I wish to append all the sheets to one if the last part split by `_` of sheet names are same across all excel files. ie., sheet 1 will append with sheet 2 since their both have common `bj`, if another excel file also have sheets with name `bj`, it will also be append to this one, same logic for sheet 3 and sheet 4.

How could I achieve that in Pandas or other Python packages?

The expected result for current excel file would be:

`bj`:

```
   a  b   c  d
0  1  2  23  2
1  2  3  45  5
2  1  2  23  6
3  2  3  45  7
```

`sh`:

```
   a  b   c
0  1  2  23
1  2  3  45
2  1  2  23
3  2  3  40
```

Code for reference:

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("*.xlsx")

for each in files:
    dfs =  pd.read_excel(each, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
    df_out = pd.concat(dfs.values(), keys=dfs.keys())
    for n, g in df_out.groupby(df_out.index.to_series().str[0].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[-1]):
        g.droplevel(level=0).dropna(how='all', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).to_excel(f'Out_{n}.xlsx', index=False)
```

**Update:**

You may download test excel files and final expected result from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m91i02ug2jawqc6/test_data.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('Downloads/WS_1.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])

df_out = pd.concat(dfs.values(), keys=dfs.keys())

for n, g in df_out.groupby(df_out.index.to_series().str[0].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[-1]):
    g.droplevel(level=0).dropna(how='all', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).to_excel(f'Out_{n}.xlsx')
```

##### Update

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("Downloads/test_data/*.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Downloads/test_data/Output_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

excel_dict = {}

for each in files:
    dfs =  pd.read_excel(each, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
    excel_dict.update(dfs)
    
df_out = pd.concat(dfs.values(), keys=dfs.keys())
for n, g in df_out.groupby(df_out.index.to_series().str[0].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[-1]):
    g.droplevel(level=0).dropna(how='all', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=f'{n}')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, if I need to iterate multiples excel file similar as `WS_1.xlsx` and append them all together?

Comment: @ahbon Each workbook will have multiple worksheets?   Are the worksheets named the same in each workbook?  Are the worksheets uniquely named?

Comment: Yes, each workbook will have multiple worksheets, but they are not named the same, but I wish to append the sheets together if last part split by `_` are same (normally they share same column names), whatever excel files it comes from. ie., `2021_q1_bj` from `data1.xlsx` and `2019_q3_bj` from `data2.xlsx`, will concatenate to one file `bj.xlsx`. If in `data1.xlsx`, we have other sheets endwith `bj` split by `_`, they will also get concatenate to `bj.xlsx` as well.

Comment: I would update a master dictionary with the output of read_excel, then pd.concat that master dictionary create df_out and then for loop and groupby.

Comment: Would you please take time to update the code?

Comment: I need sample excel files to test the code accurately.

Comment: I've updated the test excel files and the expected final result in the last part of the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236122/discussion-between-ah-bon-and-scott-boston).

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the whole process and get the final expected result with the code below.

Thanks to provide alternative and more concise solutions or give me some advices if it's possible:

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from datetime import datetime

def save_xls(dict_df, path):
    writer = ExcelWriter(path)
    for key in dict_df:
        dict_df[key].to_excel(writer, key, index=False)
    writer.save()

root_dir = './original/'

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    # print(subFolders)
    for file in files:
        if '.xlsx' in file:
            file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, file)
            print(file)
            f = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
            dict_dfs = {}
            for sheet_name in f.sheet_names:
                df_new = f.parse(sheet_name = sheet_name)
                print(sheet_name)
        
                ## get the year and quarter from the sheet name 
                year, quarter, city = sheet_name.split("_")
                # year, quarter, city = sheet_name.split("_")
                df_new["year"] = year
                df_new["quarter"] = quarter
                df_new["city"] = city
                dict_dfs[sheet_name] = df_new 
        
            save_xls(dict_df = dict_dfs, path = './add_columns_from_sheet_name/' + "new_" + file)


root_dir = './add_columns_from_sheet_name/'
list1 = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    # print(subFolders)
    for file in files:
        if '.xlsx' in file:
            # print(file)
            city = file.split('_')[0]
            # print(file)
            file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, file)
            # print(file_path)
            dfs = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None)
            df_out = pd.concat(dfs.values(), keys=dfs.keys())
            for n, g in df_out.groupby(df_out.index.to_series().str[0].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[-1]):
                print(n)
                timestr = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%f')[:-3]
                g.droplevel(level=0).dropna(how='all', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).to_excel(f'./output/{n}_{timestr}.xlsx', index=False)

file_set = set()
file_dir = './output/'
file_list = os.listdir(file_dir)
for file in file_list:
    data_type = file.split('_')[0]
    file_set.add(data_type)
print(file_set)


file_dir = './output'
file_list = os.listdir(file_dir)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df4 = pd.DataFrame()

file_set = set()
for file in file_list:
    if '.xlsx' in file:
        # print(file)
        df_temp = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(file_dir, file))
        if 'bj' in file:
            df1 = df1.append(df_temp)
        elif 'sh' in file:
            df2 = df2.append(df_temp)
        elif 'gz' in file:
            df3 = df3.append(df_temp)
        elif 'sz' in file:
            df4 = df4.append(df_temp)
            
# function
def dfs_tabs(df_list, sheet_list, file_name):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')   
    for dataframe, sheet in zip(df_list, sheet_list):
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, startrow=0 , startcol=0, index=False)   
    writer.save()

# list of dataframes and sheet names
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
sheets = ['bj', 'sh', 'gz', 'sz']    
# run function
dfs_tabs(dfs, sheets, './final/final_result.xlsx')
```